# why can't a vertex of a K-critical graph have all the neighbors of another vertex?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

The neighbourhood of a vertex $v$ is the set of all neighbours of $v$ (or, equivalently, the set of vertices adjacent to $v$), and is denoted by $N(v)$. Prove that if $u, v$ are vertices in a critical graph $G$, then $N(u)⊈ N(v)$.

A hint was provided: The proof deals with two cases of $u$ and $v$ are adjacent and not adjacent separately. One case is trivial.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @rschwieb I have changed the title as you suggested, any help with the question?

Comment: @user407151 Nope: not until I find a bit of time to look up a few definitions. But in any case I think you're a lot better off with this title! :)

Comment: @bof thank you 'not a subset' is what i meant.

Comment: I don't understand your two cases. If $N(u)\subseteq N(v)$ then $u$ and $v$ can't be adjacent; $v\notin N(u)$ because $v\notin N(v).$ (I assume your graphs are loopless since the problem is about chromatic number.)

Comment: A graph G is critical if χ(H) < χ(G) for every proper subgraph H of G. We also say a critical graph G with χ(G) = k is k-critical. That's the definition i was given in my notes.

Comment: can you show this futher how it explains that N(u)⊈N(v) as im still finding it confusing @bof. thank you for your help.

Comment: Im not sure @bof

Comment: Thank you for your help it was much appreciated @bof. If you have another suggestions regarding this proof please do let me know.

Comment: I was also given a theorem which states 'If G is K-critical, then δ(G)≥K-1.' which i was told would be useful to solve this. Is this theorem similar to what you have suggested? @bof

Comment: If $\chi(G)=k$ and some vertex $u$ has $\lt k-1$ neighbors, then deleting $u$ can't lower the chromatic number; if you could color the rest of the vertices with $k-1$ colors, there would be no problem coloring $u$. So in a $k$-critical graph every vertex has degree at least $k-1.$ I don't see how that would help to prove the thing you asked about in your question.

Comment: Ive noticed that the proof for that theorem is similar to the proof you gave for this question hence why it was probably given as a hint. Thank you again. @bof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a [critical graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_graph). Assume for a contradiction that there are vertices $u,v\in V(G)$ with $u\ne v$ and $N(u)\subseteq N(v).$ Let $h=\chi(G-u).$ Consider a proper coloring of $G-u$ with $h$ colors. Since $N(u)\subseteq N(v),$ this coloring can be extended to a proper coloring of $G$ with $h$ colors, by giving $u$ the same color as $v.$ This shows that $\chi(G)=\chi(G-u),$ contradicting the assumed criticality of $G.$